# Parse serialized data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, token

I'm attempting to read a large data set into a data frame in R. The data look like this (but with many, many more columns):

```
\xk:1520890\xdt:2015031901053801\xty:M\nty:ID\qty:0.00\qoh:0.00\qt:0.00\qp:0.00\wqty:\qre:0
\xk:1520897\xdt:2015031901064000\xty:M\nty:IA\qty:0.00\qoh:0.00\qt:0.00\qp:0.00\wqty:\qre:0
\xk:1520900\xdt:2015031901071000\xty:M\nty:ID\qty:0.00\qoh:0.00\qt:0.00\qp:0.00\wqty:\qre:0
```

Surely there's a way to do this, but I do not know where to look.

Comment: My backup plan is to cheat by using sed to filter out all the tokens, then using read.table with the backslash as a separator. Because I anticipate needing to do this again, I'd prefer to have a 'real' solution.

Comment: Using sed seems reasonable. You can call it from R.

Comment: So you just want the numeric values? and would be using the tokens as column names?

Comment: "backslash" as separator might be a bit difficult unless you know how to manage the fact R handles backslashes as escape character. I'd pick a different character, perhaps "|". You can call sed from R and gather its output as a stream.

Comment: @BondedDust, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a UNIX-alike system (but inside R) you can do this:

```
system("tr -d '\\' < test.txt")
#-----output-------
xk:1520890xdt:2015031901053801xty:Mnty:IDqty:0.00qoh:0.00qt:0.00qp:0.00wqty:qre:0
xk:1520897xdt:2015031901064000xty:Mnty:IAqty:0.00qoh:0.00qt:0.00qp:0.00wqty:qre:0
xk:1520900xdt:2015031901071000xty:Mnty:IDqty:0.00qoh:0.00qt:0.00qp:0.00wqty:qre:0
```

I'm not sure you have given a complete description but on my Mac this succeeds in what I think is desired (assuming file is named test.txt" in your working directory:

```
inp <-  system("tr -d '\\' < test.txt", intern=TRUE)
# sed might work too, but I couldn't get the correct sub-pattern.
gsub("[^0-9.]+", " ", inp)
#---------------
[1] " 1520890 2015031901053801 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0"
[2] " 1520897 2015031901064000 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0"
[3] " 1520900 2015031901071000 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0"
```

If you have a Windows machine, you may need to use `shell` instead.

Comment: I had forgotten about gsub. That will do nicely!